# connect const QString& or const QString

Tags: qt

what's the correct way to emit a signal with QString if that QString is local.
I mean I have function like this in wigdetA

```
void wigdetA::something()
{

//
//e.g
//
QTreeWidgetItem *it = this->treeWidget->currentItem();
if (it == 0)
    return;

QString s = it->text(1);

emit passToMainWindow(s);
}
```

Should I create connection like this (just const QString):

```
 connect(wigdetA, SIGNAL(passToMainWindow(const QString)), this, SLOT(passToMainWindow(const QString)));
```

or can I use const reference

```
connect(wigdetA, SIGNAL(passToMainWindow(const QString&)), this, SLOT(passToMainWindow(const QString&)));
```

Both ways work, but I though the second const& will crash the appliaction since QString s is local and it will be destroyed when the function something() exits.

or I'm missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since emitting and receiving objects are both in the main thread, Qt uses direct connection (the slot is called immediately as you do emit). In this case you local string is still on stack.

However it is always better to pass it by value, especially if connection is made between objects residing in different threads. QString uses implicit sharing (aka copy-on-write), so it does not cost much to pass it by value.

Comment: This is wrong. Cross-thread signals are queued (see Qt::QueuedConnection), thus the values are copied in each case and using const references is safe. Thus one can safely use const references, always.

Comment: @Frank, yes, you are right, thanks for correction. Cross-thread connections are queued by default. And for queued connections indeed a copy constructor will be called (having copy constructor is mandatory in order to pass an object via queued connection). For direct connections objects are passed by reference (omitting copying) if declared so. However there is no point to write SIGNAL(pass(const QString&)); SIGNAL(pass(QString)) does just fine for both cases.

Comment: For the connect statement, that's correct. For the signal/slot signatures, one should use const & though.

Answer (score 1):

with Qt5, the new connection system requires both slots to have the same argument type and connecting a signal with QString argument to a slot with const QString & will not work.

```
ObjType1 : QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  ...
  signals :
  sendInfo(QString)
}

ObjType2 : QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  ...
  public slots:
  slotObjType1::receiveInfo(const QString&)
  ...
}

void ObjTyp3::someFunction{}(
   ...
   connect(mpObj1, &ObjType1::sendInfo, mpObj2, &ObjType2::receiveInfo); // shows an error because arguments does not match
   ...
}
```

If we consider the multithreading issue, then passing by value would be the safer and more maintainable way of doing things.
However, many documentations show slots with "const QString&" arguments, though it does not allow a signal with QString argument to be connected.
Is there any magic in the "connect" mechanism that copies the (const QString &) value, when not using direct connection ? Is there a reason for everybody using signals with QString reference ?

Comment: It seems that the connection mechanism will copy the reference value when not using direct connection : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42187235/qt-signal-and-slots-are-reference-arguments-copied#comment71541112_42188017

Comment: so using "const QString &" is the best as it will be lighter when using direct connection and will be handled in case of thread inter communication

Answer (score 0):

the `emit passToMainWindow(s)` will call the slot in the mainwindow as it gets emitted. so it will be no big deal. when dealing with the qt slots they use mainly `const QString&` so i guess the framework will take care that the string wont get deleted before it was used by the slot.