# Qt signal and slots: are reference arguments copied?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals, slots

In qt framework, most library signals and slots use pointers as parameters. I was wondering, If I create a signal-slot "structure" that takes a reference as the parameter instead of the pointer, will the whole parameter be copied, or just 4 bytes (32-bit system) like in a regular c++ reference?

I am asking this because I noticed something when I create a signal/ slot methods with the reference parameter. When I then `connect` them, the autocomplete mechanism in QTCreator doesn't hint me with reference parameters like he would do with pointer parameters. He hints me with the regular parameter. For example:

I create a signal and slot:

```
...
signals:
     void mySignal(int& parameter);
private slots:
     void on_mySignal(int& parameter);
```

I then attempt to connected them and Qt doesnt add `&` for reference in parameter:

```
...
connect(this, SIGNAL(mySignal(int)), this, SLOT(on_mySignal(int)));
```

I have to manually change to:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(mySignal(int&)), this, SLOT(on_mySignal(int&)));
```

Thus I am wondering, does reference even work with signal/slot? I would appreciate all help.

Comment: Your premise is flawed. Regular C++ references have no size as they are not objects. You cannot, for example, use `sizeof` to get the size of a reference. Also you should stop using the deprecated signal/slot syntax. The proper syntax is `connect(this, &Class::mySignal, this, &Class::on_mySignal);` which avoids you having to worry about that.

Comment: I understand, thank you. But to answer the main question: If using signal/ slots with reference, is big amount of data being copied?

Comment: I would expect a copy of the `int` even though you specified an `int &`. You can test that by assigning to the argument in the slot and see if the parameter you passed in changed.

Comment: int is just an example. Im my code I have large containers passed in arguments as references. Thats why it concerns me. Also thank you very much for showing the new signal/slot connecting method. It is indeed very convienient.

Comment: Note that Qt containers such as `QVector` use copy on write, so copying `QVector`s around doesn't copy the data. If you are using `std::vector`s they will actually copy the data.

Comment: No, most of my parameters in signals/slots are `Qvector<something>&`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you send and receive a reference, on the same thread, per default no copy will be made. If you do anything else, including sending/receiving a value or sending a reference to another thread, one, two or even three copies will be made.

What happens depends on the connection type and the assurances QT needs to know that references remain valid through the call. A direct connection on the same thread resolves to a simple function call, so very little can happen to the underlying data. A queued connection, however, offers no guarantees for when the call will actually happen, therefore QT will make copies to preserve data integrity. QT implicitly queues signals crossing thread boundaries.

If either side is pass-by-value then QT copies the data to not affect the underlying object's state.

For more information, [have a look at this blog post](http://www.embeddeduse.com/2013/06/29/copied-or-not-copied-arguments-signals-slots/).

Comment: Johan, you are not correct. Copying is not depends on threads, it depends on slot connection type. Even in same thread ref arguments are copied in case of queued connection. Read Qt documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum

Comment: the doc say that when the connection is queued, the argument is copied to be stored in an event behind the scene. Does it mean that the engine test if the argument is a reference and if so will copy the value ?